# Beamer Custom ToC not working as expected

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, protected-macro

I hacked a table of frames for beamer and got a weird situation I do not understand.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\insertframetitle}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title1}
Some text1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title2}
Some text2
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{List}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The two entries in the list are "List 1" and "List 1" whereas they should be "Title 1" and "Title 2".

If I remove the `\protect` then I get a weird error message:

```
! Argument of \XC@col@rlet has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.15 \end{frame}
                
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

**What** is going wrong here?

*Note 1:* It looks like this minimal offending examples crucially depends on quite a number of details. For example, if I remove the `allowframebreaks` in the first two slides, everything is fine (provided I also remove the `\protect` - if I leave it in I get the wrong entries).

*Note 2:* I use the background template as only this template is called on all continuation slides; moving to frametitle is no option.

Comment: \insertframetitle doesn't contain only the title, but also code to *insert* the title, it is not the right command, try `\addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\beamer@frametitle}`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Tried. Worked. Thanx. Cool.